# vlooup in workbook to and paste into another workbook in a specific column which change one row down every day

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, vlookup

I want to make a code in VBA to make my work more efficient and need some help from good brains to do that. Ive tried a nummerous times my self, but cant find a way to make it work. Here is my problem:

I have a value in Column A I need to find in workbook1 and worksheet2 which is the lookup value for the value in column Q. The same workbook is retrieved from an internet source and the number of rows is dynamic as the xls-file change every day. Further, I want to paste the Vlookup value into workvbook2 and worksheet2 in Column B. the number of rows is going to grow one row every time as one cell is filled. Hence I need a find first blanc row code. Workbook 2 is already open.

Is there someone out there who can help me with this problem?

Many thanks in advance!!!

Comment: What have you tried so far? StackOverflow is not a 'Code this for me'-site.

Answer (score 0):

this is what ive tried, and I cant wrap my head around how to integrate the vlookup part of the code.

Sub vlookup()

Dim SourceLastRow As Long
Dim OutputLastRow As Long
Dim sourceBook As Workbook
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim outputSheet As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'source workbook
Set sourceBook = Workbooks.Open("https://sharepoint.com/sites/investorservice/Delte%20dokumenter/Arbeidsrutiner/Behandling%20av%20tegninger.xlsx")

'worksheets
Set sourceSheet = sourceBook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set outputSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

'here i need to define a vklookfunction in Sourcesheet.
outputSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub